# Expanding code columns into readable text

Tags: sql

What is best practice when your database has a one or two character code that you want to convert to a human readable value?

For example, I have a STATUS_CD column where the values are A,P,C,etc. There is no lookup table, but here are the meanings:

| STATUS_CD | MEANING |
| --- | --- |
| A | Active |
| P | Pending |
| C | Closed |

I know I can try a bunch of code and run Explain Plan to compare, but I'm guessing best practice has a clear answer here, but this is hard to search on!

A couple of key facts:

- I don't own the tables. I can't change the structure.
- There are no lookup tables. If I need one, I have to create it myself.

The two ideas I have for this are to create a temp table and do a join, or to do a CASE WHEN in the select. Any suggestions on which will perform better and be easier to write/maintain? I probably have 3-5 codes per table that will need to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about SQL, I would definitely create a dedicated table and use joins, because it's the easiest way to maintain it and make some updates without changing anything in other parts of the code (as long as the structure remains the same).
And its the only way to have a database that respects [normal forms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normal-forms-in-dbms/). This supposes we are talking about *relational* database, if its not the case this contraint might be of less importance.

For any other procedural language, it would be a global variable, defined in a settings file, with a type adapted to the language itself.